# Mongodb: When do we need to expire shopping carts?

Tags: mongodb, express, shopping-cart

I'm building an e-commerce website by ExpressJs + Mongodb and I'm stuck with this concern:
When do we need to expire the cart ( remove the cart and return the product to inventory ) technically ? Whenever user visit the cart? or should I need a cron job?

I've followed this article: https://www.infoq.com/articles/data-model-mongodb

Here's my cart model's implementation:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const CartItem = new Schema({
    product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    quantity: Number
});

const Cart = new Schema({
    userSessionId: String,
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: [ 'active', 'completed', 'expiring', 'expired' ],
        default: 'active'
    },
    items: [ CartItem ],
    modifiedOn: { type: Date }
});

Cart.static({
    summary: function(params, cb) {
        this.aggregate([
            {
                $match: { userSessionId: params.userSessionId }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$items'
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'products',
                    localField: 'items.product',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'product'
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$product',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: { userSessionId: '$userSessionId' },
                    count: { $sum: '$items.quantity' },
                    total: { $sum: { $multiply: [ '$product.price', '$items.quantity' ] } }
                }
            }
        ], (err, results) => cb(err, results[0]));
    },
    addProduct: function(params, cb, test) {
        var d = new Date();

        if (test) {
            d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 10);
        }

        this.findOneAndUpdate(
            { userSessionId: params.userSessionId },
            { $set: { modifiedOn: d } },
            { upsert: true, new: true }, (err, cart) => {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }

                const index = cart.items.findIndex((item) => {
                    return item.product.equals(params.productId);
                });

                if (index === -1) {
                    cart.items.push({
                        product: params.productId,
                        quantity: params.quantity
                    });
                } else {
                    cart.items[index].quantity += parseFloat(params.quantity);
                }
                cart.save(cb);
            });
    },
    updateQuantity: function(params, cb) {
        this.findOneAndUpdate(
            { userSessionId: params.userSessionId },
            {},
            { upsert: true, new: true }, (err, cart) => {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }

                const index = cart.items.findIndex((item) => {
                    return item.product.equals(params.productId);
                });

                if (index === -1) {
                    return cb(new Error('Can not find product in cart'));
                }
                cart.items[index].quantity = params.quantity;

                cart.save(cb);
            });
    },
    findItem: function(params, cb) {
        this.findOne({ userSessionId: params.userSessionId }).exec((err, cart) => {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }

            const index = cart.items.findIndex((item) => {
                return item.product.equals(params.productId);
            });

            if (index === -1) {
                return cb(new Error('Can not find product in cart'));
            }

            cb(null, cart.items[index]);
        });
    },
    removeProduct: function(params, cb) {
        this.update(
            { userSessionId: params.userSessionId },
            {
                $pull: { items: { product: params.productId } },
                $set: { modifiedOn: new Date() }
            },
            cb
        );
    },
    getExpiredCarts: function(params, cb) {
        var now = new Date();

        if (typeof params.timeout !== 'number') {
            return cb(new Error('timeout should be a number!'));
        }

        now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - params.timeout);

        this.find(
            { modifiedOn: { $lte: now }, status: 'active' }
        ).exec(cb);
    }
});

mongoose.model('Cart', Cart);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use some kind of distributed session to store the shopping cart!

I think you are looking for something like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g32awc4HrLA

It uses `expressjs-session` and `mongodb` then you have a distributed cache and it will work with multiple instances of your application.

Comment: hello @marco, I'm using expressjs-session actually. My concern is about ```When do we need to expire the cart ( remove the cart and return the product to inventory ) technically ? Whenever user visit the cart? or should I need a cron job?

```

Comment: If you are using `mongodb` you can set a `ttl` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/ that will remove the document after a certain period. If you do that, you dont't need to use a `cron job`. You can expire after X days.

Comment: Thank you, I will try with you suggestion